# Dynamic construction of RegEx based on user input

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to get user input match it against a string variable, when I passed a literal string to `new RegExp(/\bjavascript/)`, it works, but I tried `new RegExp('\b' + this.input)` or `new RegExp('/\b' + this.input + '/');` it fails.

Here is the code

```
 var lang = 'javascript'
 let patern =  new RegExp('/\b' + this.input + '/');
 console.log(patern.test('lang'));
```

where 'input' is declare within my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When input comes from a user, it's a good idea to escape the string using the following:

```
RegExp.escape = function (s)
{
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

You call it like this:

```
 let patern =  new RegExp('\\b' + RegExp.escape(this.input));
```

That way it Works even when the input has special characters in it, like '`\`' or parenthesis-

Answer (score 2):

Remove the slash from the beginning and end and escape backslashes:

```js
this.input = "St";

let pattern =  new RegExp('\\b' + this.input, 'i');

console.log(
  "Stack Overflow".match(pattern)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Luca that works but i tried adjust it to be case insensitive like: let pattern =  new RegExp('\\b' + this.input + '\\i'); but fail again any reason why?

Comment: RegEx takes flags as the second parameter, `new RegExp('\\b' + this.input, 'i');` will give you a case-insensitive regex